# PHP Throws "Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '1' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php71/pear') in *directory* on line 2

Tags: php, html, php-7

My basic file structure looks like this:

```
public_html
├── admin
|  ├── _css
|  ├── _php
|  |  ├── login
|  |  |  └── register_script.php
└  └── register.php
```

And when I run this on register.php in /public_html/admin/

```php
require '_php/login/register_script.php';
//OR
require *full directory*;
//OR
require dirname(__FILE__).'_php/login/register_script.php';
//OR
require $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT].'_php/login/register_script.php/';
```

They all return the same error:

```php
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '1' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php71/pear') in /home/servername/public_html/admin/register.php on line 2
```

I did use hard refresh on the browsers, as the 'line 2' changes to 'line 3' if I enter a line before require. Thanks!

**SOLVED: Changing the directory to ./_php/login/register_script.php works for me**

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include exactly where in your directory structure you are using those `require` functions.

Comment: Is this actual code? The only way I can conceive to get "Failed opening required '1'" is to run something like `require '1';` :-?